# browser history in javascript

Tags: javascript, navigation

I write the following on onClick of an HTML button;

```
javascript:history.go(-1)
```

It does not go to the history page. Instead it shows the following...

*Webpage has expired*

*Most likely cause:*
•*The local copy of this webpage is out of date, and the website requires that you download it again.*

*What you can try: 
     Click on the Refresh button on the toolbar to reload the page. After refreshing, you might need to navigate to the specific webpage again, or re-enter information.*

[image]

Comment: Sounds like the previous webpage sent "no cache" headers and MSIE chose to follow them religiously. But where is the question, what are you actually asking?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript, it either has to do with going to a page that previously contained POST data (see Boldewyn's answer) or it has to do with the HTTP headers being sent by the page being set to something that's preventing caching, specifically via the `Cache-Control` header. Note that if you're doing this on `localhost` you may get different behavior than when you upload it to your server.

[See here](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL) for a good reference. I'll copypasta the important bits in any case:

> Useful Cache-Control response headers include:
>
> max-age=[seconds] — specifies the maximum amount of time that an representation will be considered fresh. Similar to Expires, this directive is relative to the time of the request, rather than absolute. [seconds] is the number of seconds from the time of the request you wish the representation to be fresh for.
>
> public — marks authenticated responses as cacheable; normally, if HTTP authentication is required, responses are automatically private.
>
> private — allows caches that are specific to one user (e.g., in a browser) to store the response; shared caches (e.g., in a proxy) may not.
>
> no-cache — forces caches to submit the request to the origin server for validation before releasing a cached copy, every time. This is useful to assure that authentication is respected (in combination with public), or to maintain rigid freshness, without sacrificing all of the benefits of caching.
>
> For example:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
```

Comment: I think, IE's error message is misleading here. It's most probably a POST vs GET issue. If it were a simple expired cache, IE would just re-GET it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably the case, when the previous page was received with an HTTP POST request. There's almost nothing you can do against it on the JavaScript level.

The problem is, that POST requests are used to *change* stuff. So, if the browser would send the same request again, it would submit the same change information again. This can be as simple as a double-posted comment and as destructive as two times transferring 10000 bucks.

If you can controll the previous page, you have to do this:

```
Browser: POST prev-site
You -> deliver a redirect to prev-site (hence force a GET request)
       instead of directly showing it
Browser: GET prev-site
User: Clicks link to this-site
Browser: GET this-site
User: history.go(-1)
Browser: GET prev-site
All: rejoice!
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the "Webpage has expired" message you can add method='get' to your  element to switch from POST to GET.

Note that this puts the form parameters in the URL instead of in the HTTP request body.

On a related note, the "Webpage has expired" message seems to occur over HTTPS when the same exact action succeeds over HTTP.